# Task Parallel Library - Blocking Operations?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

How does the .NET Task Parallel Library handle tasks with blocking operations? In the C++ Concrt library you have the `Context::Oversubscribe` method, but I haven't found such a thing in the .NET library? Is the `LongRunningTask` option the corresponding way to handle blocking tasks?

.i.e: in C++ you would do:

```
auto my_task_func = []
{
     //Do work...
     Context::Oversubscribe(true);
     // Short or long blocking op.
     Context::Oversubscribe(false);
     //Do more work.

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TPL uses a hill-climbing algorithm to find the optimal number of threads without cooperation from the tasks themselves. It just keeps injecting threads until the task completion rate does not improve further.

Comment: The `ThreadPool` (which is used by TPL behind the scenes) also receives notifications that one of its threads started blocking and uses this information to decide when to create new threads.

Comment: svick, good comment. I also think this is true, although not documented. I can't seem to find a reference for that right now.

Comment: I don't know whether it's actually document, but my source is *CLR via C#*, 3rd edition, page 759: “However, if any of these threads voluntarily block […] then Windows notifies the thread pool that one of its threads has stopped running. The thread pool now […] creates a new thread to replace the blocked thread.”